# Getting fixed size Image from PHCachingImageManager

Tags: ios, uitableview, photokit

I'm trying to get thumbnails from my `PHCachingImageManager` so that I can put them into the built-in `imageView` in my `UITableViewCell`s.

```
NSLog(@"thumbnail size: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(AssetGridThumbnailSize));
[self.imageManager
    requestImageForAsset:asset
        targetSize:AssetGridThumbnailSize
       contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
           options:nil
     resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {

       NSLog(@"image size: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(result.size));

       // Only update the thumbnail if the cell tag hasn't changed. Otherwise, the cell has been re-used.
       if (cell.tag == currentTag) {
           cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
           cell.imageView.image = result;

       }
}];
```

I can see that AssetGridThumbnailSize = 80 x 80 (40 x 40 retina) from the logs:

> thumbnail size: {80, 80}

and I've set the contentMode to `PHImageContentModeAspectFill` but when I get the images back they are all different sizes and it makes the `UITableView` look very chaotic.

How can I make the `PHCachingImageManager` give me back an image of the right size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While posting the question, I figured out the answer so I decided to continue posting and hopefully this will help someone else.

The `targetSize` is just a suggestion. In order to really control the size of the returned images you have to pass in a `PHImageRequestOptions` object with `resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact`.

```
PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;

[self.imageManager requestImageForAsset:asset
                 targetSize:AssetGridThumbnailSize
                contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                    options:options
              resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
```